# In a pandas dataframe I would like to assign a value to a column based on filtering other columns to certain values

Tags: python, pandas

For example, I want to change all values in the 'ModelPrediction' column to 1 where the 'AgeGrp' column is equal to [0, 5], and where the 'Sex' column is equal to male, and the 'PClass' column is equal to '1' as well as '2'.

I have changed the data type of the AgeGrp, Pclass columns to object already.

[image: table]

My attempt is below:

```
train.loc[train['Sex'] == 'male' & ['Pclass'] == 1 & ['Pclass'] == 2 & ['AgeGrp'] == (0, 5], 'ModelPrediction'] = 1
```

I'm very new to all things python/pandas, any help is appreciated!! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, but one of your conditions, that `Pclass` is both 1 and 2, is impossible, the syntax for intervals does not exist, and you'll want parentheses to separate each of your conditions:

```
train.loc[(train['Sex'] == 'male') & ((train['Pclass'] == 1) | (train['Pclass'] == 2)) & (train['AgeGrp'] > 0) & (train['AgeGrp'] <= 5), 'ModelPrediction'] = 1
```

Comment: Right, didn't mean to say that there are no ways of working with intervals; just that there is no built-in Python/pandas syntax for doing so, and that what OP wanted to do requires a bit more work.

Comment: Yes, then agree, :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you need add `()` and [`Interval`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Interval.html), also there is twice condition with `Pclass`, I think need [`isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.isin.html) here if need check both values:

```
train = pd.DataFrame({'Sex':['male','female','male'],
                      'Pclass':[1,0,1],
                      'AgeGrp':[pd.Interval(0, 5, closed='right'),
                                pd.Interval(6, 10, closed='right'),
                                pd.Interval(0, 5, closed='right')],
                        'ModelPrediction':[0,1,0]})
print (train)
      Sex  Pclass   AgeGrp  ModelPrediction
0    male       1   (0, 5]                0
1  female       0  (6, 10]                1
2    male       1   (0, 5]                0

train.loc[(train['Sex'] == 'male') & 
          (train['Pclass'].isin([1, 2])) & 
          (train['AgeGrp'] == pd.Interval(0, 5, closed='right')), 'ModelPrediction'] = 1  

print (train)
      Sex  Pclass   AgeGrp  ModelPrediction
0    male       1   (0, 5]                1
1  female       0  (6, 10]                1
2    male       1   (0, 5]                1
```